# Syntax error in urlrewrite.xml configuration file

Tags: java, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter, dtd, xml

I have an error I can't seem to resolve with my Tuckey urlrewrite configuration file in Eclipse. I've narrowed the offending rules down to these entries:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.1//EN"
    "http://tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.1.dtd">

<urlrewrite>

    <rule>
        <from>/admin/**</from>
        <to>/app/admin/$1</to>
    </rule>
    <outbound-rule>
        <from>/app/admin/**</from>
        <to>/admin/$1</to>
    </outbound-rule>

    <rule>
        <from>/**</from>
        <to>/app/static/$1</to>
    </rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

This file reports a validation error in the Eclipse XML editor:

> The content of element type "urlrewrite" must match
>   "((rule|class-rule)*,outbound-rule*,catch*)".

If I remove either the `<outbound-rule>` or the second `<rule>` (routing "/**") the error disappears.

As far as I can tell I have adhered to the DTD, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You just have to make `outbound-rule` the last element.

```xml
<urlrewrite>

    <rule>
        <from>/admin/**</from>
        <to>/app/admin/$1</to>
    </rule>

    <rule>
        <from>/**</from>
        <to>/app/static/$1</to>
    </rule>

    <outbound-rule>
        <from>/app/admin/**</from>
        <to>/admin/$1</to>
    </outbound-rule>

</urlrewrite>
```